# Dividing two simple select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two simple select statements and just want to divide the first one by the second one.

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT INITIATIVE_ID) 
FROM GPD_ERROR_WARNING_NEW

SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT SAVINGS_ID)
FROM GPD_SAVINGS_REGULAR
```

The first select statement results in 300
The second select statement results in about 1500, so just looking for that magic .2

I know it is simple to do by hand but looking to automate this and make it a view as it needs to be updated every hour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work, but it leaves you open to a "divide by zero" error:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT INITIATIVE_ID) FROM GPD_ERROR_WARNING_NEW) /
  (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT SAVINGS_ID) FROM GPD_SAVINGS_REGULAR)
FROM DUAL;
```

This will give you a null result instead of an error if the second (denominator) count comes up as zero:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT INITIATIVE_ID) FROM GPD_ERROR_WARNING_NEW) /
  NULLIF((SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT SAVINGS_ID) FROM GPD_SAVINGS_REGULAR), 0)
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Would this return `0` in the OP's example because of integer division?

Comment: @Dillon Tagle - In addition, something worth mentioning is that the DUAL table is an Oracle Only construct. For other databases (such as SQL Server) setting up the FROM statement is not necessary.

Comment: @jlars62 - no. I wondered the same thing so I tried it (using different tables) and I got a "decimal" value. I'm on Oracle 11 here.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query like this (in sql):

```
SELECT
(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(INITIATIVE_ID) FROM GPD_ERROR_WARNING_NEW) /
ISNULL((SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(SAVINGS_ID) FROM GPD_SAVINGS_REGULAR), 0)
FROM DUAL;
```